# Touch event fired before button button gets loaded

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I am trying to create a little quiz where you have a simple question and 4 different answers which are represented by buttons.
I have a container for the buttons and the button creation function basically deletes all buttons and creates new ones with new respective answers on them. Those buttons are triggered by a touchstart and touchend event. I chose this to work on mobile but I am running into a bug that I cannot fix somehow. Whenever I double click a button events are triggered twice and basically skip a question. The problem here is that I cannot block that behaviour. When I test this on the console I noticed that buttons are not triggered twice, but the button that gets created in the next iterations is immediately triggered without even being loaded on the screen. My function looks like this:

```
function generateButtons(answers, correctAnswer, currentQuestion, currentPoints, quizArray){
    // generating 4 buttons with different possibilties to answer 
    document.getElementById("buttonContainer").innerHTML = "";
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.innerText = answers[i];
        btn.value = answers[i];
        btn.id = "testbutton" + i;
        (function(btnValue, btnID){
            btn.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
                quizArray[currentQuestion-1][2] = btnValue;
                buttonColoring(btnID, btnValue, correctAnswer);
        })})(answers[i], btn.id);
        (function(btnValue){
            btn.addEventListener("touchend", function() {
                sleep(1000);
                quizArray[currentQuestion-1][2] = btnValue;
                var t1 = performance.now();
                checkAnswer(btnValue, correctAnswer, currentQuestion, currentPoints, quizArray);
        })})(answers[i]);
        docFrag.appendChild(btn);
    }
    document.getElementById("buttonContainer").appendChild(docFrag);
    document.getElementById("questionNumber").innerHTML = "Frage: " + currentQuestion;
    document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = "Punkte: " + currentPoints;
}
```